# Optimial settings for FBO depth texture attachment

Tags: opengl

I have been using render buffers till now when using depth test with custom FBOs. Now I need to replace those with depth texture (as I need to read it in a shader).I am looking at different sources like [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/) and see that GL_FLOAT is used as data type.In [other](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Examples) examples GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE is used and sometime even GL_INT.Also internal format can be GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16 , GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24 , GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32.

My question is which variation is best in terms of performance and quality?I am sure that with depth component of 32bit  the depth test should be more precise but what about the data type?Which one should be usually used?

Comment: Traditionally, some years ago, one would use 24bit depth (with or without stencil), or 16bit on some cheap cards. 32bit integer depth was never really supported well. Nowadays, I'd just go with float, it's more or less universally supported, fast, and not full with contorted [quirks](http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/love_your_z_buffer.html) like the integer stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, `GL_FLOAT`, etc. as you described is actually the [`Pixel Transfer`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer) type. This is the type that OpenGL uses when it reads/writes pixel data from/into a buffer, in OpenGL the driver will do data type conversion to ensure that the read / written values are compatible. In OpenGL ES this was completely removed, but in all cases the internal format of a depth renderbuffer has to be one of `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT<X>{F}` or `GL_DEPTH<X>_STENCIL<Y>`. These formats define both the data type and the format used internally.

For best performance, match the component type to the pixel transfer type to avoid driver pixel conversion. (e.g. `GL_FLOAT` for pixel transfer is a good match for `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F`). However, this really only applies when you want to use the contents of the depth/stencil buffer to do something outside of OpenGL (e.g. reading or writing the buffer using a PBO).

The majority of the time, you can ignore the pixel transfer format and type when you allocate a depth texture (besides ensuring that they are *legal values* for the given internal format). You probably are not going to read it outside of OpenGL or feed it data from client memory, which is the only time this applies.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore " Not to set it up at all?  Or use just any type?

Comment: @MichaelIV: Use any type, because I am fairly certain you are passing `NULL` as the pixel data when you call `glTexImage2D (...)` to setup your texture attachment. `NULL` means there is no pixel transfer going on in the first place :P If, however, you were going to read the texture into client memory using a PBO and `glReadPixels (...)` then the pixel transfer format / type would be very important and you would follow the rules I explained above - match component size / type to minimize driver overhead.

Comment: @MichaelIV: I realize I forgot to discuss the precision / performance trade-offs in my answer. They were already touched on in comments to the question, 24-bit depth buffers are the most widely supported for window pixel formats... in FBOs you have a _LOT_ more flexibility, but if you can get away with a smaller format you will get better performance simply because it reduces memory bandwidth. FP is actually **less** precise overall, but allows for a greater range of depth values, particularly in the fractional range very close to the near plane; improving precision in some areas.

Comment: An interesting caveat is that in a perspective projection, you already have greater precision nearer to the camera. So FP depth buffers by themselves actually make things worse when you want to resolve objects farther away. But if you flip the depth range around, you can use an FP depth buffer to more evenly distribute precision (than a fixed-point depth buffer) when using perspective projection. For more details, [check out this article.](http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/attack-of-the-depth-buffer/).