# How to create a 24 bit depth buffer openGL

Tags: opengl

I am learning about how to use framebuffers in opengl. From what I understand so far, if I want to render an image to a framebuffer I would first create a texture and then attach it to a framebuffers colour attachment. The code might look something like this:

```
glGenTextures(1, &handle);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, handle);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

This code generates a texture handle, binds it, and generates an empty texture for the target GL_TEXTURE_2D. Because the format is specified as GL_RGB and the data type is GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, then after rendering to this texture the data would look like:

```
R   G   B   R   G   B   R   G   B   R   G   B   R   G   B   R ...
23  25  40  1   4   67  255 255 255 0   0   1   3   5   55  72 ...
```

So there are 3 channels each composed of the single byte data. Now I think I can attach this texture as a colour attachment of a framebuffer like this:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbohandle);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbohandle);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, handle, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Hopefully my understanding of this is correct. Now consider trying to render depth values to a texture instead. This might look like:

```
glGenTextures(1, &handle);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, handle);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbohandle);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbohandle);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, handle, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

In this case I generate an empty texture this time able to store one float value for the depth (where the texture has a single channel per pixel). So each value in our depth texture has a 32 bit precision. I have often seen referenced however that the depth component is stored a 16 or 24 bits. For example in the[Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTextureFormat.Depth.html) engine documentation on RenderTextures it is stated that "*On OpenGL it is the native "depth component" format (usually 24 or 16 bits), on Direct3D9 it is the 32 bit floating point ("R32F") format.*"

Indeed looking at the [Khronos](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format) wiki I see that there exists GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32 and GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F. If I were to use GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24 for the format of my texture (to create a depth texture with 24 bits of precision), what should I use as my data type? As far as I know there isn't a 24 bit float. Is my understanding of framebuffers and textures (as described here) correct in terms of how the data is stored? How would one create a 24 (or 16) bit precision depth buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I were to use GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24 for the format of my texture (to create a depth texture with 24 bits of precision), what should I use as my data type?

GL_UNSIGNED_INT. But according to this answer, it’s not important unless you want to access depth buffer data from CPU: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19307871/126995

> How would one create a 24 (or 16) bit precision depth buffer?

16 bit depth buffers contain integers just like 24 bit buffers. The correct data type for them is GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT.

Comment: Interesting, so ths raises some more questions. I was under the impression that the data type (GLFloat, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, etc) was the data type of the value that was stored in the actual texture once rendered. That's why I thought that for the case of color we used GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE since each channel was one byte (0-255). In the case of the depth buffer we would need a float I would think and not integers. If I am understanding you though the actual value (i.e. say a depth of 0.65 at a pixel) isn't related to the data type. The data type just specifies how many bytes to use?

Comment: I guess one thing that I don't understand is an unsigned int is usually 32 bits as is a float. So why does setting the data type to GL_UNISGNED_INT mean we will only use 24 bits (the last 8 are left unused??) while using a GLFloat gives us 32 bits used? Also if I do read from my depth texture I should be getting floats even though the data type can be set to GL_UNSIGNED_INT? Is that correct?

Comment: @James: it is a totally moot point as you're not going to transfer any pixel data to the GL in your call. The `format` parameter only tells the GL how to interpret the client data, it is totally irrelevant for the internal format of your texture.

Comment: @James “The data type just specifies how many bytes to use?” how many bytes OpenGL will use on the CPU. The GPUs are free to use whatever internal format they please.

“if I do read from my depth texture I should be getting floats even though the data type can be set to GL_UNSIGNED_INT?” you’ll get integers, probably from 0 to 2^24-1. If you like float specify GL_FLOAT. It won’t affect GPU formats, but OpenGL will convert the data for you.

Comment: Has anyone done a comparison? It's not just a matter of preference which one you use, you can represent numbers in either that you can't in the other (large odd ints become even floats, etc., large floats might clamp to the max int or even wrap and of course small floats are all 0.) This could end up being a major source of "z-fighting" depending on how the conversion is done and how a "24 bit float" is represented. On the other hand, floating point arithmetic on the CPU can be much faster, so it's worth knowing.

Comment: I learned more [here](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Depth-testing). What I said should still be true, except that the range for floats is 0 to 1, so what matters is how small numbers are represented. The same thing that happens to large numbers happens inversely to small numbers - small ints are grouped by the nearest float because some float bits are spent on the exponent, and small floats are all 0 because they're below the first converted int. My link refers to a curve that redistributes values so the small end gets higher resolution, that's a good starting point.